# Common Table Expression Select where last observation was at a location

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I have the following tables

Location table

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

Package table

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

PackageObservation table

```
[PackageID] int
[LocationID] int
[Date] datetime
[Quantity] int
```

For a given location I want to select packages where the last observation of the package was at the location

What is the Transact SQL?
I think it involves a common table expression but I cant figure it out.

More information.
The following almost does it, but I don't really want to assume that the identity field is in date order

```
 select max(id) ,packageid
  from packageobservation o1
  where not exists ( 
  select o2.id from packageobservation o2 
  where o2.[date] > o1.[date] )
  group by packageid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following SQL statement:

```
  DECLARE @locationID int = 1

  SELECT po.PackageID, MAX(po.[Date]) AS DateAtLocation 
  FROM PackageObservation po 
  WHERE po.LocationID=@locationID
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PackageObservation po2 
                  WHERE po2.PackageID = po.PackageID AND  
                        po2.LocationID <> po.LocationID AND 
                        po2.[Date] >= po.[Date] )
  GROUP BY po.PackageID
```

For better speed you can also add combined index on [LocationID],[PackageID] and [Date].
Seems to me that using CTE is not necessary here.